# How to get the query execution time with database inspector?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, database-inspector

I am using the [database inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database) to query the database. However, I want to know the execution time to optimize the performance of the query. Does anyone have any idea of getting the execution time of a query?